# Scrolling Image: the drawing shapes cover the scroller - how to fix it?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My View displays the image as a first layer, than I display the bunch of the shapes (rectangles, lines, circles) over the image as a second layer.
The image has a scroller because it can't be fully displayed on my View.
The strange issue is enclosed in the fact, that the shapes are displayed over the scroller.
How can I fix it?

Here's my View:

```
 <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="500" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="500" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Image Source="{Binding VM.ManipulatedImage}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Stretch="None"           
            Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>

        </ScrollViewer>


        <ItemsControl 
            ItemsSource="{Binding VM.Shapes, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}"
                            Fill="{Binding Fill}"
                            Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
                            StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}"
                            Opacity="{Binding Opacity}"
                              />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: That isn't strange at all. The ItemsControl is not a child element of the ScrollViewer. Instead, both are children of the top level Grid, in the same cell, and the ItemsControl lies on top of the ScrollViewer.

Comment: How can I fix it? If I place Items controls inside the scrollview it says - not pssible. If I place items controls before image , it does not show it.

Comment: @J.Doe did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Place the ScrollViewer around the Grid. The Grid is happy to have multiple children.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="500" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="{Binding VM.ManipulatedImage}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Stretch="None"           
        Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
    <ItemsControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding VM.Shapes, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}"
                        Fill="{Binding Fill}"
                        Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
                        StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}"
                        Opacity="{Binding Opacity}"
                          />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: If I do it the way you suggested, the scroller is disabled and not working

Comment: It's hard for me to see what you're after, since I don't have your image, or the collection of items that you're binding to, or a screenshot of what you're seeing. You're saying that "the scroller is disabled and not working" but since there is nothing that will make it disabled, I'm interpreting that as meaning that the scrollbar *is* enabled but there is nowhere to scroll to, which means it thinks it is showing everything it needs to. I'm guessing the window/control you're looking at it in is >500x500 - try making that smaller, the scrollbars will work (unless there's something outside it).

Comment: P.S. (unrelated; but I thought it might be a helpful general learning point for WPF bindings) the binding to ItemsSource does not need to be TwoWay, since the "ItemsSource" property of the ItemsControl is not going to be updating that collection.

Comment: no, the image is big and I can scroll it in my initial version where I pointed to another problem. It 's not important what kind of shapes I place exactly because the problem is with the image scrolling